# Assigning table cells colors based on condition - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here I have a textbox that takes a number then based on that displays a table with random numbers after a button is clicked. That done, now what I'm trying to achieve is basically adding either blue or red if the random number within the cell is (num % 3 == 0) or (num % 2 == 0). Then later displaying the average of all the numbers below the table. I've been stuck on this for a while now so I figured I asked for help. Any tips on how I can approach this?

```js
var min = 1;
var max = 100;

function drawTable() {
  //Get the div reference for the body
  var div1 = document.getElementById('tableDiv');

  //Creates a table element
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");

  var totalRows = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputBox").value);
  var cellsInRow = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputBox").value);

  //Creating rows
  for (var rows = 0; rows < totalRows; rows++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    /*if ( rows % 3 == 0)
    {
        //background
        bg = "class='red'";     

    }
    else {
        bg = "class='blue'";
    }*/

    //Create cells in row
    for (var cells = 0; cells < cellsInRow; cells++) {

      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

      var cellText = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);

      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    //Add the row to the end of the table body
    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
  //Appends <table> into the <div>
  div1.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="inputBox">
<input type="button" value="Generate Grid" id="generateBtn" onclick="drawTable()">

<div id="tableDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: I have just updated your question to include an MCVE. Please remember to check that your code is actually working before asking a question--I have to add a missing closing curly bracket at the end of your code.

Comment: @Terry Sorry about that, I didn't notice that I didn't include the closing curly brace. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work - we added a variable to store the sum of the iterated numbers (to calculate the average later), and set background-color to the appropriate color while iterating over the nodes.

```js
var min = 1;
var max = 100;

function drawTable() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById('tableDiv');

  var tbl = document.createElement("table");

  var totalRows = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputBox").value);
  var cellsInRow = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputBox").value);

  var sum = 0; // Store sum of numbers

  for (var rows = 0; rows < totalRows; rows++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var cells = 0; cells < cellsInRow; cells++) {

      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      sum += randomNum; // Increment sum
      if (randomNum % 3 === 0) {
          cell.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red")
      }
      else if (randomNum % 2 === 0) {
          cell.setAttribute("style", "background-color:lightblue")
      }

      var cellText = document.createTextNode(randomNum);

      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
  //Appends <table> into the <div>
  div1.appendChild(tbl);
  var avg = sum / (totalRows * cellsInRow); // Calculate avarage
  div1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Average: " + avg)) // Add average text
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="inputBox">
<input type="button" value="Generate Grid" id="generateBtn" onclick="drawTable()">

<div id="tableDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Fissio. By the way, is there anyway that I could get the new generated table to replace the old one? As of right now it just keeps adding one at the bottom of the existing one. Like is it possible for me to add the new table to the old one basically replacing it or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the below example adds the classes you want simply using `cell.className`. To do this, it moves the `bg` calculation into the for loop.

Also, you weren't using the value of `getRandom` in your `cellText`. We also then use this value to calculate the `bg`.

To bear in mind: if you want to use the value of a variable outside of a given code block, it's good practice to define that variable at the top of the block you need to recall it within.

If you want to go further to work out the averages of the numbers, you'll have to start saving each value as it's created to an array. Once all rows are generated, you can calculate a final row based on these values.

Hope that helps!

```js
var min = 1;
var max = 100;

function drawTable() {
  //Get the div reference for the body
  var div1 = document.getElementById('tableDiv');

  //Creates a table element
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");

  var totalRows = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputBox").value);
  var cellsInRow = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputBox").value);

  //Creating rows
  for (var rows = 0; rows < totalRows; rows++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    //Create cells in row
    for (var cells = 0; cells < cellsInRow; cells++) {

      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

      var cellText = document.createTextNode(getRandom);
      var bg = '';

      if ( getRandom % 3 == 0)
      {
          //background
          bg = 'red';
      }
      else if ( getRandom % 2 == 0) {
          bg = 'blue';
      } else {
          bg = '';
      }

      cell.appendChild(cellText); 
      cell.className = bg;
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    //Add the row to the end of the table body
    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
  //Appends <table> into the <div>
  div1.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="inputBox">
<input type="button" value="Generate Grid" id="generateBtn" onclick="drawTable()">

<div id="tableDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it helps my understanding a little more. I am new to Js, mainly learning from youtube tutorials.